# How to compare the type of the var?

Tags: python, if-statement, var

I've began a very basic program where you have to find the number randomly chosen by the computer. I successfully added the randomizer to the program, yet I couldn't find how to compare the type of the asked number so that a message is printed whenever you type letters instead of numbers for example.

I tried this type of command

```
if type(nbredevine)!=int:

    print ("""I asked you for an integer. Don't mess with me.""")
```

unfortunately this isnt working, and even though I've searched for it in the internet and on this site, i haven't been able to find something that fits this special situation.

I haven't been able to make the isinstance function work in this case. Is it because I'm too much of a neophyte ?

Thank you guys, and happy holidays for those of you who are in holidays.

Comment: you want `isinstance(nbredevine, int)`, perhaps you also need to make sure the user input is not a string too: the `input()` function will by default give any user input as a string

Comment: Yes, Python can detect how new you are, and disables certain advanced features, like type comparison /s

Comment: Chances are that you actually have the input as a string. If you want to see if it looks like an integer, try and cast it to `int` and see if it errors.

Comment: Seriously though, your input will never be an integer. Anything you type will be a string, even if it contains digits.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was supposing that i was misusing the command,  not that python would block the function.

Comment: @jeremycg so how can i change the type of the input() command ? thank you for your response.

Comment: So, to elaborate on what @MadPhysicist is saying, `'12'` is *always* a `str` object, whereas `12` is an `int` object. That `'12'`, the `str`, happens to contain text which would represent an `int` doesn't matter, it is still a `str`. if you are using `input()` then the result will always be `str` type.

Comment: The problem is that my program prints this whenever I type some letters in the program's nbredevine var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 8, in <module>
    nbredevine=input("""Try to guess the number randomly chosen by the computer (between 0 and 100) :""")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Comment: @wwii I basically started to program today, years after doing basic programs like this in C. I don't understand the code of the page you sent me. Could any of you possibly explain it to me ?

I just wanna understand, I don't want to bother anyone

Comment: Are you using Python 2? That would explain the error. Please **always** provide a [mcve], which is a requirement for these sorts of questions. In any case, you definitely shouldn't be learning Python 2, which is essentially at its official end of life (Jan 1, 2020)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input`, you always get a string. If the string contains only digits, it can be converted to an integer, but it's still a string. There are a couple of things you can do.

If you are only interested in non-negative integers, you can check using  [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
if nbredevine.isdigit():
    value = int(nbredevine)
    # use integer value
else:
    print('Not an integer')
```

If you want to bypass all the fluff and check directly, you can just try converting to an integer:

```
try:
    value = int(nbredevine)
except ValueError:
    print('Not an integer')
else:
    # use integer value
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I still have the same error.
Here is the error message i get :
Traceback (most recent call last): File "python.py", line 8, in <module> nbredevine=input("""Try to guess the number randomly chosen by the computer (between 0 and 100) :""") File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Comment: @JPRouve.  That error has nothing to do with the posted code. You're trying to reference an undefined variable named `test` somewhere.

Comment: Well, it is because i try to input "test" inside of my nbredevine var

Comment: @JPRouve. That's not what the error says, unless you forgot quotes around `test`. FWIW, you can select an answer even after your question gets closed.